# Would a shaken up bottle of soda weigh more than a unshaken one?

Tags: mass

I asked this question on a different physics forum and some cited conservation of matter, but some others didn't know whether it would be applicable in this instance. So I thought I would ask the experts here.

Answer (score 8):

To all practical purposes it would weigh the same.

That said, there are negligible effects.
Its easy to assume the bottle is sealed and no gas can escape; but that is not completely possible, negligible gas will escape, and more if the bottle is shaken and the gas pressure is increased by gas leaving solution. The remaining mass is then reduced.

Even more negligible, the force of gravity acts upon the energy of the object, principally its mass but not exclusively. You may know photons, that are massless, are affected by gravity.
When the bottle is shaken, energy is introduced to it. It may heat up slightly. 
Consequently it will experience negligible stronger gravity. Really really $\frac{1}{astonomically}$ tiny effect.

If the bottle was plastic and expanded slightly then it would be more buoyant on earth, but not on the moon.

Comment: If the bottle was plastic and expanded slightly then it would be more buoyant on earth, but not on the moon.

Comment: added to answer

Answer (score 0):

If you shake a bottle which is completely sealed and no mass can cross its boundary i.e. it is a closed system, then upon shaking it, you are doing work on the water in the bottle which would consequently raise its temperature for some time. This would result in an extremely small (not even noticeable) increase in the weight of the bottle. If the bottle is made of some flexible material, the pressure inside the bottle would increase and would result in the increase in the volume of the bottle, which inturn would result in increase in buoyant force which would decrease the apparent weight of the bottle.

Answer (score 0):

By shaking it you will increase its temperature, which means that you will increase its energy. By the relativistic equality of mass and energy, in turn you will increase its mass. Clearly this effect is really too small to be appreciated.